# How to locate /mykeypair.pem in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services

I was following the tutorial by Amazon [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/gsg-hue.html). It was all good until here which I don't quite understand.

```
In the command, replace ~/mykeypair.pem with the location and file name of your .pem file and replace ec2-###-##-##-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com with the master public DNS name of your cluster.
```

I know where to get the master public DNS name but I have no clue on how to locate the mykeypair.pem file.

Comment: copy `mykeypair.pem` into home folder and use  `~/mykeypair.pem`

Comment: where can I copy or find mykeypair.pem ? @nafas

Comment: did you download the .pem file from amazon?

Comment: i have the key pair in my EC2 but how do I download it ? There is no download button @nafas

Comment: @kylas A keypair is only downloadable at the time of creation after that for security reasons AWS will not allow it to be re-downloaded. In case if you dont have the older pem key. Kindly create a new one and then recreate the EMR cluster.

Comment: thanks @Raghav i have it solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In specific to the command,

```
ssh -i ~/mykeypair.pem -N -L 8157:ec2-###-##-##-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8888 hadoop@ec2-###-##-##-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

The location of where you already have downloaded from AWS and kept mykeypair.pem is what matters. Assume that you have downloaded it on your desktop and the dir path is /home/user/desktop/mykeypair.pem, then the above command would be simply

```
ssh -i /home/user/desktop/mykeypair.pem -N -L 8157:ec2-###-##-##-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8888 hadoop@ec2-###-##-##-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

PS:

[1] Kindly check the permission on that key must be read-only for owner (chmod 0400 filename)

[2] Also in that Tutorial: Step3, Point 8... shows the details about EC2 key pair. Either you have to create a new one which AWS will ask you to download.. or use an existing one for which you have already downloaded it.

[3] Keypair is only downloadable at the time of creation after that for security reasons AWS will not allow it to be re-downloaded. In case if you dont have the older pem key. Kindly create a new one and then recreate the EMR cluster.

Answer (score 0):

They mean that in the line of command they provide you with, that contain the part "~/mykeypair.pem" you should replace that part with the name of the .pem file you have.

Meaning, in this: `ssh -i ~/mykeypair.pem -N -L 8157:ec2-###-##-##-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8888 hadoop@ec2-###-##-##-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com` replace ~/mykeypair.pem with your file name and execute the command.